# Wordpress / Woocommerce, how to access current product loop Query on category page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In my code I am adding some filter parameters with shortcode in sidebar. I need to access current product loop Query of category from where I can get all attributes of products in query loop. Can someone tell me where I can find more information about this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a WooCommerce-specific hook called [woocommerce_product_query](https://wp-kama.com/plugin/woocommerce/hook/woocommerce_product_query) or a more general hook from the WordPress core called [pre_get_posts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/). Both work a pretty similar way - they allow you to access the current WP_Query object and modify it.